# Correct or not? $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin(x))}dx\stackrel?=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+\ln(2\pi)\right]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I got the idea from  [here](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/official-oloa.pdf)

(1)
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin(x))}dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+\ln(2\pi)\right]$$

I am not quite sure it corrects, because I check it with a calculator and it only gave 9 decimal places. So can anyone please help me to verify (1)?

Comment: It follows from the integral representation for Gregory coefficients. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200613/why-does-int-0-infty-frac-ln-1x-ln2x-pi2-fracdxx2-give-the

Comment: Another idea is to exploit the "Cantarini's trick" $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(at)e^{-bt}\,dt = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$ with $a=x$ and $b=-\log(2\sin(x))$ to get $$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x \sin(x t)\left(2 \sin x\right)^{t}\,dx\,dt.$$

Comment: With that trick, the problem boils down to managing an Euler beta function and its derivative.

Comment: @mahdi shafici Thank you for the mentioned reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can anyone please help me to verify it*?

The announced equality is **not correct**. We have

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin(x))}dx \color{red}{\neq}\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+\ln(2\pi)\right],
> $$

as is seen with *standard methods of numerical evaluation*:
$$
\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin(x))}dx&= \color{red}{1.04471}13415676906315535681507671\ldots \tag1
\\\\
J=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+\ln(2\pi)\right]&=\color{red}{1.04471}46850072181679012146131844\ldots \tag2
\end{align}
$$

Evaluating the integral with a [composite trapezoidal rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643770/error-of-the-composite-trapezoidal-rule) ensures that $I\color{red}{<}J$ ($f$ being the integrand, we have $\left|f^{(2)}(x)\right|<50$ over $[0,\pi/2]$, we take $n=10\,000$) .